# A timer that adds a second when it is paused

Tags: c++, windows

This should be a normal timer that runs until it's either paused or exited. The code is exited by the NextStep() Function. And The timer is supposed to pause and stay paused until it's pressed again.

However, when I press the spacebar, the timer stops only after adding another digit to the timer.

An example of the problem:

01sec

02sec

I press the spacebar.

03sec (+1sec)

The timer pauses.

On the other hand, the code that executes the NextStep() works fine without any delays.

I tried rewriting it in different ways, but none of them worked.

```
#pragma once

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <thread>


using namespace std;




void NextStep();
bool pause = false;
bool stop = false; 



void wait(int milliseconds)
{
    int counter = 0;

    while (pause) {
        char ch = _getch();
        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            pause = !pause;
        }
        else if (ch == 27)
        {
            cout << "\033c";
            NextStep();
            stop = true;

        }
    }


    while (counter < milliseconds && !stop)
    {


        if (pause) {
            continue;
        }

        if (pause == false) {
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
            counter++;
        }
    }

}


void timer() 
{
    int seconds = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int hours = 0;

    
    while (true) 
    {

        cout << "\033c";
        cout << setfill(' ') << setw(55) << "    Timer   \n";
        cout << "                                          ";
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hours << "h ";
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << minutes << "min ";
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << seconds << "sec ";
        wait(60);

        seconds++;

        if (seconds == 60) {
            minutes++;
            seconds = 0;
        }
        else if (minutes == 60)
        {
            hours++;
            minutes = 0;
            seconds = 0; 
        }
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            char ch = _getch();
            if (ch == ' ')
            {
                pause = !pause;
            }
            else if (ch == 27)
            {
                cout << "\033c";
                NextStep();
                stop = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the NextStep() function:

```
void NextStep()
{
    string option;
    correct = false; 
    cout << "\033c";
    cout << "Loading...";
    Sleep(1300);
    cout << "\033c";
    cout << "What would you like to do next?" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "To change your password TYPE: password" << endl;
    cout << "To use a calculator TYPE: calculator" << endl; 
    cout << "To use a timer TYPE: timer" << endl; 
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Type your choice: ";
    UserInput();

}
```

Comment: I think you are not using `<windows.h>` but `<conio.h>` is windows too.

Comment: what is your question? You describe the code, but it is not completely clear what the problem is.

Comment: `wait(60); seconds++;` ? 60 milliseconds don't make a second

Comment: I want the timer to stop when I press the spacebar, but it only stops after adding another digit to the timer.

Comment: "wait(60); seconds++; ? 60 milliseconds don't make a second"

I don't know why, but wait(60) was the only way I could make the timer wait for a second.

And the second++; adds a second to the timer.

Comment: you seem to expect some sort of concurrency when you wait for `stop` to change its value in `wait`, but this is not going to happen. This code is completely sequential

Comment: how should I change the code?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: please edit the question to clarify, what the code should do, and what it does instead.

Comment: where is the definition of the `NextStep` function?

Comment: It's in a different header file. I don't have any problems with that function.

Comment: but all others looking at your code have a problem with the function, becuase its definition is missing. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am not sure how to add the code to the comments.

Comment: don't add code in comments. You can edit the question

Comment: The only place `pause` can become true is in `timer()`, and that loop only repeats approximately once per second.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand all the workings of your code, but I think I understand that you need to have a timer that can be started, paused, and restarted. Also if I understood correctly the timer should not be affected (= paused) by the fact that the thread is in sleep.

So, here is an implementation of such a timer that might help you (at least for part of your problem) :

```cpp
#include <chrono>

template<typename T>
class Timer
{

public:

    void start()
    {
        m_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }

    void pause()
    {
        m_elapsed += get_current_elapsed();
        m_start = {};
    }

    void reset()
    {
        m_start = {};
        m_elapsed = {};
    }

    int64_t get_elapsed()
    {
        return (m_elapsed + get_current_elapsed()).count();
    }

private:

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> m_start{};
    T m_elapsed{};

    bool is_started()
    {
        return m_start.time_since_epoch() != T{};
    }

    T get_current_elapsed()
    {
        return is_started() ? std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - m_start) : T{};
    }
};
```

And here is an example of how it can be used :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    Timer<std::chrono::seconds> timer;

    timer.start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    timer.pause(); // "optional"
    std::cout << timer.get_elapsed() << std::endl; // 1

    timer.start(); // "optional"
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    timer.pause(); // "optional"
    std::cout << timer.get_elapsed() << std::endl; // 2

    timer.reset();
    timer.start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    timer.pause(); // "optional"
    std::cout << timer.get_elapsed() << std::endl; // 1

    return 0;
}
```

`Timer` is a template, so instead of `std::chrono::seconds` you can use any of the following types depending on the precision you want for the timer :

- std::chrono::nanoseconds
- std::chrono::microseconds
- std::chrono::milliseconds
- std::chrono::seconds
- std::chrono::minutes
- std::chrono::hours
- std::chrono::days
- std::chrono::years

Comment: It seems that OP's goal is "have a timer that can be started, paused, and restarted **by keypresses**"

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. However, I'm still having trouble understanding how it works and how to adapt it to my needs, as
I am not very advanced in coding. Unfortunately, it didn't quite solve my problem, since it wasn't exactly what I was looking for. 

This comment perfectly encapsulates, what I was trying to achieve: "It seems that OP's goal is "have a timer that can be started, paused, and restarted by keypresses" – 
Ben Voigt"